# spring boot application properties not loaded

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to read application properties but which are not loaded by default.In Repository it tries to read yml file username but it is not getting the value for api.username but it is getting null value.Please help me to find where am missing the configuration.

**Main:-**

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Spring Batch Processor call snippet in job:-**

```
@Bean
public PersonItemProcessor processor() {
    return new PersonItemProcessor();
}
```

**Spring Batch Processor:-**

```
@Component
public class PersonItemProcessor implements ItemProcessor<PersonDO,PersonDO> {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(PersonItemProcessor.class);

    @Override
    public PersonDO process(final PersonDO person) throws Exception {
        getService().printUserName(person.getQueueId());
        log.info(person + "");
        return person;
    }

    @Bean
    public SService getService(){
        return new SService();
    }

}
```

**Spring Service:-**

```
@Service
public class SService {

    public boolean printUserName(String password){
        return getSRepository().printUserName(password);
    }

    @Bean
    public SRepository getSRepository(){
        return new SRepository();
    }
}
```

**Spring Repository:-**

```
@Repository
public class SRepository {

    @Value("${api.username}")
    private String username;

    public boolean printUserName(String password){
        System.out.println("username:"+username+":password:"+password);
        return (username!=null?true:false);
    }
}
```

**application.yml**

```
api:
 username: UserName1
spring:
 batch:
  job:
   enabled: false
```

**Output:-**

```
username:null:password:password@123
```

**Update location of application.yml is src/main/resources**

Comment: Seems to be the `@PropertySource("classpath:application.yml")` is missing under `@EnableAutoConfiguration`

Comment: @WildDev but it is there in location of application.yml is src/main/resources

Comment: Indeed. Add the 'PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer' as a static '@Bean' to the 'Application' class

Comment: Remove your `@Bean` method and simply `@Autowired` your dependency into your service. You are currently creating a new instance as soon as you need it (check the reference guide for Bean lite mode). The same applies to your `@Bean` method that constructs the service.

Comment: @M.Deinum thanks for your reply am getting below error if I remove Bean and use Autowired:***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START***************************

Description:

Field repository in com.binding.issue.SService required a bean of type 'com.binding.issue.SRepository' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.binding.issue.SRepository' in your configuration.

Comment: Then fix your component scanning (you omitted the packages but I suspect your application class is not in a parent package of the other packages (then those beans would be detected by component scanning).